# Is it possible to use androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle WITHOUT toobar

Tags: android-actionbar, android-toolbar, androidx

```
*android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true*

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
```

I migrate to androidx package.

All project is success build except this:

```
package android.support.v7.app does not exist

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;



        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,  R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
```

in my activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
public class MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity extends androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,  R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)

}
```

In new  `androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` I must use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.
But in my code I use action bar. So as result not compile.
The questions are:

1. Is it possible to use `androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` **WITHOUT** toobar
2. Is it possible to use `androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` **WITH** actionbar ?